# Action in state-transition diagram

Tags: uml

I'm discovering the state-transition diagram and I read that an action must be atomic and fast , but I didn't find the reason of these conditions.Please Can you explain to me why ?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

State machines often operate in embedded systems where they react to actors setting switches. Those actions are expected to be "fast as lightning" or approximately as fast as a transistor. So you would not do any calculation inside to approximate Pi.

If the nature of your system does not require that you can also put anything time consuming inside your actions.

Comment: Thank you Thomas Kilian but what about atomicity ?

Comment: That's about interuptability. To cover that, state machines have sub-states. Atomic relates to the state itself.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker you may want to read some more real-life articles, e.g. those at [Quantum Leaps document repository](http://www.state-machine.com/resources/articles.php#UML)